# Error on adapter class. ViewHolder views must not be attached when created

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I have a problem with my code, I created two adapter within one recyclerview. I put them both in a class, and I need this adapter to return an Viewholder depending on some situations.

Here is my Adapter code:

```
public class CurrentUserTaskListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

public List<Task> taskList;
private static final int ITEM_TYPE_PUBLISHED_TASK = 1;
private static final int ITEM_TYPE_ASSIGNED_TASK = 2;

public CurrentUserTaskListAdapter(List<Task> taskList) {
    this.taskList = taskList;
}

public class AssignedTaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public TextView tvTagAndDate;
    public TextView tvStatus;

    public AssignedTaskViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        tvTagAndDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTagAndDate);
        tvStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
    }
}

public class PublishedTaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public TextView tvTagAndDate;
    public TextView tvStatus;

    public PublishedTaskViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        tvTagAndDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTagAndDate);
        tvStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
    }
}

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (taskList.get(position).getAssignedTo() == null)
            return ITEM_TYPE_PUBLISHED_TASK;
        else
            return ITEM_TYPE_ASSIGNED_TASK;
    }

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

    if(i == ITEM_TYPE_ASSIGNED_TASK){
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_curent_user_assigned_tasks_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new AssignedTaskViewHolder(viewGroup);
    }
    else if (i == ITEM_TYPE_PUBLISHED_TASK){
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_current_user_pending_tasks, viewGroup, false);

        return new PublishedTaskViewHolder(viewGroup);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    if(viewHolder instanceof AssignedTaskViewHolder){
        final AssignedTaskViewHolder assignedTaskViewHolder = (AssignedTaskViewHolder) viewHolder;
    }
    else if (viewHolder instanceof PublishedTaskViewHolder) {
        final PublishedTaskViewHolder publishedTaskViewHolder = (PublishedTaskViewHolder) viewHolder;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return taskList.size();
}}
```

The problem i have is that i get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean attachToRoot)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6796)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)....and so on

In the method getItemViewType i verify which TYPE an object from my list is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix this part it is in example:

```java
if (i == ITEM_TYPE_ASSIGNED_TASK) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_curent_user_assigned_tasks_item, viewGroup, false);

    return new AssignedTaskViewHolder(view);
} else if (i == ITEM_TYPE_PUBLISHED_TASK) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_current_user_pending_tasks, viewGroup, false);

    return new PublishedTaskViewHolder(view);
}
```

Problem is that you are passing parent layout where ViewHolder's item layout should be.
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you ! That was my problem. but you know what do i do with onBindViewHolder method?

Comment: No problem. Please mark question as answered. OnBindViewHolder  you should pass some data that should be displayed in single item of your list. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523308/when-onbindviewholder-is-called-and-how-it-works

Comment: how can i get position of my element in list in AssignedTaskViewHolder ?

Comment: in onBindViewHolder method position is "int i". And inside ViewHolder it self it is simply getPosition()