# RecyclerView calling onCreateViewHolder, getItemCount() > 0, but onBindViewHolder is not been called

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, data-binding

I am struggeleing with some weird issue i am facing the following state

- RecyclerView Calling onCreateViewHolder
- getItemCount() > 0
- Items are preseneted and scrollable
- **onBindViewHolder is not been called so they have no data**
- No exception in log

Did someone faced a simmeler issue?

Comment: Isn't it only being called during scrolling? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37524217/1501613

Comment: It is not been called during scroll.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the code? Perhaps also a screenshot of what it means that there are no data.